# SVN - can't delete a tag with special characters in the name

Tags: svn

I'm cleaning up some old SVN repos to prepare to migrate them to Git, and found some tags with special characters in the name that I'm having trouble deleting.

How can I delete these? Escaping the chars doesn't work. Single quotes doesn't work. SVN converts the special chars ino if i escape them.

```
svn delete -m "cleanup" 'https://svn.repos.com/repo/mobile repo/tags/${TEST_VALUE}'
svn: URL 'https://svn.repos.com/repo/mobile repo/tags/$%257BTEST_VALUE%257D' does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `svn delete -m "cleanup" 'https://svn.repos.com/repo/mobile repo/tags/${TEST_VALUE}'`
>   `svn: URL 'https://svn.repos.com/repo/mobile repo/tags/$%257BTEST_VALUE%257D' does not exist`

This isn't complaining about *special characters*. It's telling you that a tag named `${TEST_VALUE}` doesn't exist. And, I bet it doesn't. The `%257` you're getting is merely the percent code for `{`.

If this is a shell script, use double quotes instead of single quotes around the URL. This will allow `${TEST_VALUE}` to be interpolated by the shell.

```
svn delete -m "cleanup" "https://svn.repos.com/repo/mobile repo/tags/${TEST_VALUE}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded tortoisesvn and let it deal with the special chars. Much easier.